# Why foreach loop skip one value in html table?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display data in html using a PHP foreach loop. I get my data array (`$studentHistory` in the code below) by calling [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) after query results are returned.
However, when I write out html in the foreach loop using echo, 
values in the inner loop are skipping one iteration.

```
echo '<table>
      <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>STUDENT ID</th>
      <th>ROOM ID</th>
      <th>DATE</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      ';
foreach ($studentHistory as $item=>$row)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $value)
    {
        echo "<td style='width: 150px; border: 1px solid black;>".$value."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

If I replace the inner loop to echo without HTML, it shows all data:

```
...
foreach($row as $value)
{
    echo $value." ";
}
...
```

I'm using PDO and running MySQL 5.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please dont post Pictures of code. Post the actual text please

Comment: Usually you don't need that 2nd `foreach` loop. Just output the value directly from the `$row` variable. Ex. `$row['name_of_column']`. But we can't verify that without seeing your code.

Comment: Sounds both unlikely and too observational. Looking at the browser rendition alone doesn't explain the actual output. Not reproducible without more context.

Comment: Seems you're missing ending **single quotes** here for style attribute. It should be `echo "<td style='width: 150px;border: 1px solid black;'>".$value."</td>";`

Comment: Sorry for posting pictures of code .
I'm new here so I don't know well how to ask question . 
Thanks for yours correction .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing quote on your td style attribute value.

As @Always Sunny pointed out specifically in his comment, the correct line of code for your inner loop would be the following:

```
echo "<td style='width: 150px;border: 1px solid black;'>".$value."</td>";
```

In general, if you print invalid HTML via echo from PHP, your output won't appear correct.

Comment: it should be a comment though

Comment: TYPO's should only be a comment and then Vote to close as a TYPO

Comment: Hmm. Didn't realize that was a rule. Some way I can delete my answer then?

Comment: Yea, click the delete link under the answer

Comment: I guess I'll have to check on my computer later. My phone doesn't show that option.

Comment: I see the delete link on my desktop browser, but I can't delete it now since the answer was accepted. I have edited both the question and answer to hopefully make up a little bit for this mistake of mine.